# Minecraft Forge 1.8 - ServerProxy not working on SinglePlayer

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm writing a mod in Forge 1.8 and I'm making use of the SidedProxy system. I added some items/blocks for testing, but my mod mostly needs to control logic on the server side of things/write and read some data when saving.
From my understanding, in a minecraft game, there is always a server, which in singleplayer is the internal server. However, when running from eclipse, the ServerProxy never runs as I see no output from the print statement, and the block handler doesn't get registered.

To be clear, I currently have an event handler that detects block break and place events. It works when on the commonProxy or clientProxy. However, I need this to be on the logic side, whether that be on the Dedicated Server or Internal Server, which should be in the ServerProxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that in Forge, the internal/integrated server is counted as `Side.Client` and `SidedProxy` will use the `ClientProxy` for it. So in order to create logic based events, you can use `if(!event.world.isRemote)` inside of your event handlers in order to check if it is a server that's running the code.

[Answer on MinecraftForge Forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php/topic,27833.msg142833.html)